# Getting n-th row in a group - SAS / SQL

Tags: sql, sas

any hints how do I get the *n*-th element from the group. SAS 4GL is preferred, SQL will do.

From the list of transactions below, I would like to extract a row corresponding to a 2nd (by date) transaction per each customer.

**Input:**

[image: input table]

**Output:**

[image: output]

Customer C from the example above has just one transaction, hence there is no rows corresponding to him in the output table.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's the SQL engine? If it supports window functions then you need ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY transaction_date) as row_num ... WHERE row_num = 2

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Sounds like SAS will be the engine (by the lack of any other DB tag).  SAS SQL doesn't support windowing functions.

Comment: OP: if you solely mean SAS PROC SQL please use the tag [tag:proc-sql], otherwise indicate what SQL engine you are happy with using.

Comment: How do you want to handle multiple records on the same date?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways you can accomplish this using SAS. The easiest being to sort the data set and then use a data step to output the records you want.

```
proc sort data=have;
by Customer TransactionDate;
run;

data want(drop=counter);
set have;
by Customer TransactionDate;
retain counter;
if first.Customer then counter=1;
else counter+1;
if counter=2 then output;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to achieve the desired result set is by applying windowing functions. Please, check the query below.

```
SELECT
    c.TransactionDate
    , c.Customer
    , c.Product
    , c.Quantity
    , c.[Purchase Value]
FROM (
    SELECT
        TransactionDate
        , Customer
        , Product
        , Quantity
        , [Purchase Value]
        , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY TransactionDate) AS Ranking
    FROM transactions
) AS c
WHERE c.Ranking = 2;
```

I hope this help you!

**EDIT**

This query works in case you're working with an engine that supports windows functions how I'm using in the query above (SQL Server in this case).

Answer (score 1):

This code will handle the case of multiple items bought on that day. I used `Retain` Functionality and kept a count of sub-groups.

Data: I added two extra item to A & B on the same day

```
data have;
 infile datalines dlm=',' dsd;
 informat Transaction_Date yymmdd10.;
 format Transaction_Date yymmdd10.;
 input Transaction_Date Customer $ Product $ Quantity Purchase_Value;
 datalines;
2018-01-15, A , Milk , 1 , 100
2018-01-28, A , Onion , 2 , 140
2018-01-28, A , corn , 2 , 140
2018-02-13, B , Carrot , 1 , 50
2018-03-20, B , Rice , 10 , 40
2018-03-20, B , tomato , 10 , 40
2018-04-14, B , Carrot , 1 , 50
2018-06-02, C , Candy  ,5 , 125
;
run;
```

Code: The Counter is your Nth row

```
proc sort data=have; by Customer Transaction_Date; run;
data want;
set have;
by Customer  Transaction_Date ;
retain outter;
retain inner;
retain counter;
if first.Customer then do; outter=1; counter=0; end; else outter+1;
if first.Transaction_Date then do; inner=1; counter+1; end; else inner+1;
if counter=2 then output; 
run;
```

Output:

```
 Transaction_Date=2018-01-28 Customer=A Product=Onion Quantity=2 Purchase_Value=140 outter=2 inner=1 counter=2
 Transaction_Date=2018-01-28 Customer=A Product=corn Quantity=2 Purchase_Value=140 outter=3 inner=2 counter=2 
 Transaction_Date=2018-03-20 Customer=B Product=Rice Quantity=10 Purchase_Value=40 outter=2 inner=1 counter=2
 Transaction_Date=2018-03-20 Customer=B Product=tomato Quantity=10 Purchase_Value=40 outter=3 inner=2 counter=2
```

Comment: This is the only answer the handles multiple rows in the same day.  But is this needed in the question?

Answer (score 0):

1. if you are trying to do in database processing then @alfonsohdez08  is the way to go .
   Otherwise @J_Lard  is the way to go.
   One another way by using proc sql is shown below

   ```
   proc sql;
   create table want(drop = rnk) as 
   select a.*,
   (select count(transaction_date) from have b
   where a.customer=b.customer
   and a.transaction_date>=b.transaction_date) as rnk
     from have a 
   where calculated rnk = 2;
   ```